# Text file contains the assigned variable, how to save in hash?

Tags: string, perl, variables, serialization, hash

I write the perl script, and I assigned $k="bag". I write $k===1234 inside a text file, then use perl to read the file and save it in hash. But the output I get is like '$k' => '1234', but I wish to get 'bag' =>'1234'.

The contents in text file will automatically save as string? or word? but I want it in a variable.
Because there are many pairs that are needed to save in a file? and needed to updated if have the new pair. Is it possible to do it in file? or what is the way I can do?

Comment: Please show your code that does all this.  Exactly _how_ you do it matters.

Comment: So you want to invent a new template language. What problem are you having exactly?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is clearly a duplicate question, and an XY-problem. You want to store data to file in a way that you can read it back and import it in variables. This is called [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). There are many ways to serialize data in Perl, the native Data::Dumper, or JSON, or YAML, XML, etc. There is no need to invent your own way, just use an existing one. For simplicity, you could just use Data::Dumper. `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%hash;` will print the data structure as Perl code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read a file in Perl, you'll get the contents of the file. Perl will *not* interpret the contents of the file as code and will not replace variables.

Instead, you will have to replace the variables in there yourself – essentially, you would be creating your own template language. If you only want to replace scalar variables this is typically fairly easy. The core idea is that you have to create a hash containing the variables (e.g. `my %variables = (k => "bag")` and then run a regex over your file contents to replace occurrences of the variables: `$contents =~ s/\$(\w+)/$variables{$1}/g`.

But there are some detailed decisions to be made:

- When should the variables be expanded – directly when the file is read, or after the file structure has been parsed into a hash? It is typically safer to expand the variables at a later stage, in case the variables would contain the `===` delimiter. For example, to expand variables in the keys and values of a hash table:

  ```perl
  my %expanded = map { s/.../.../gr } %parsed;
  ```

  Note the use of the `/r` flag so that the regex substitution returns the replaced result instead of modifying the input string, here the implicit variable `$_` due to using the `map` operator.
- What happens if the file references a variable that doesn't exist? Then it might make sense to `die` with an error message. We can include the code in the replacement part of the regex substitution with the `/e` flag:

  ```perl
  $contents =~ s{\$(\w+)}{ $variables{$1} // die "Unknown variable: $1" }ge
  ```